# how to turn off ipv6 at startup from console

Tags: ipv6

I am a old-fashioned Debian user. And I am confused and frustrated about some differences between Ubuntu and Debian. For example, I tried to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and to the end, I added:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then I run `sysctl -P`

which runs fine.

Then I checked

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

which output:

```
1
```

Now I am confused because with `netstat -tulpen` I can still see the machine is listening on IPv6.

I feel that this is hidden away and I'm upset about it.  Is there anything else like this I should know?

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: If you're seeking help on AskUbuntu, you probably shouldn't be insulting Ubuntu that much...

Comment: @Jos I did reboot.

Comment: @the_Seppi if you are a developer and modify such basic things in a absolute unusual way, I expect at least a README in the relevant folder. Everything else is a disrespect for the user who loses time making detective work to find out what you modified in a deep depression moment. From this point of view its crap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no reason what so ever to turn IPv6 off. It will not be used if there are no IPv6 router in your network.

So follow the "Don't fix if it isn't broken". And IPv6 isn't broken.

And there are no difference how Debian is doing this.

But if you really don't want IPv6, which there are no reason what so ever to not want, just blacklist the ipv6 module and reboot.  No need to fix in `sysctl.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

actually for many applications IPv6 does cause issues, internal networks many ISP's are still have no IPv6 and both Debian and Ubuntu will choose IPv6 by default and suddenly turn off IPv4 and anything using IPv4 will not work.

Teamspeak3 is a prime example, webmin also has an issue with this as well if your connected via IPv4 and suddenly Debian or Ubuntu turns if off then you lose connection.

So Until both Debian and Ubuntu fix this issue yes many people will want to turn it off.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  We use a Q&A format here.  Our model is to host questions and answers about Ubuntu *without chitchat or distraction*.  This discussion does not make an attempt to answer the question that was asked (How to turn off IPv6).  https://askubuntu.com/tour